# Access to text in Json Data in PHP

Tags: php, json

I would appreciate it if you could help me access the "text" of this Json. I tried but I could not, I leave the PHP code.

Code in php to access and extract texts:

```
$url = $url_to;
$array = array();    

while(1) {
    $file = fopen("links.txt", "a");
    $json = json_decode(file_get_contents($url));
    $filter_array = array_filter($json->params->tag->to_posts->bordes->node->to_caption->bordes->node);
    foreach($filter_array as $object_return){
        echo $object_return->code.'</br>'; 
        fwrite($file, $object_return->code);
        fwrite($file,"\n");
    }
    fclose($file);
```

This is the json data:

```
    {  
   "params":{  
      "tag":{  
         "name":"examples",
         "is_top_media_only":false,
         "media":{  },
         "to_posts":{  
            "bordes":[  
               {  
                  "node":{  
                     "id":"168970",
                     "to_caption":{  
                        "bordes":[  
                           {  
                              "node":{  
                                 "text":"Yes, its very strong..."
                              }
                           }
                        ]
                     },
                     "shortcode":"BBB1",
                     "edge_media_to_comment":{  
                        "count":2
                     },
                     "taken_at_timestamp":15156,
                     "dimensions":{  
                        "height":1078,
                        "width":1080
                     },
                     "display_url":"http://example.com",
                     "edge_liked_by":{  
                        "count":73
                     },
                     "owner":{  
                        "id":"40237"
                     },
                     "thumbnail_src":"http://example.com",
                     "thumbnail_resources":[  
                        {  
                           "src":"http://example.com",
                           "config_width":150,
                           "config_height":150
                        },
                        {  
                           "src":"http://example.com",
                           "config_width":240,
                           "config_height":240
                        },
                        {  
                           "src":"http://example.com",
                           "config_width":320,
                           "config_height":320
                        },
                        {  
                           "src":"http://example.com",
                           "config_width":480,
                           "config_height":480
                        },
                        {  
                           "src":"http://example.com",
                           "config_width":640,
                           "config_height":640
                        }
                     ],
                     "is_video":false
                  }
               },
               {  
                  "node":{  
                     "id":"16738",
                     "to_caption":{  
                        "bordes":[  
                           {  
                              "node":{  
                                 "text":"Hahaha its cool"
                              }
                           }
                        ]
                     },
```

I need to access all the texts of the json, because there are more, but i have stayed.
As you can see, I was trying to extract it, but it always generates an error of type sdtClass.
Thanks for you!

Comment: array_filter only works on an array.

Comment: So, should i change my logic?

Comment: Start with `json_decode (...,true)`  this type of issue has been solved hundreds of times on SO.  Keep researching.  This is a duplicate question, so I will not answer.

Comment: Try putting it true, but it does not work. Can you tell me what the error is and I look for it? thank you very much!